# "If $A$ is a good matrix then $A^TA$ is even better"

Tags: linear-algebra

From some MIT notes [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-085-computational-science-and-engineering-i-fall-2008/study-materials/nutshell.pdf)

It says that if $A$ has a nullspace consisting of only the zero vector, then the columns of $A$ are linearly independent and $A$ is a "good" matrix.

It goes on to say that as $A$ is good, $A^TA$ also has independent columns and that $A^TA$ is then invertible, symmetric, and positive definite. "If $A$ is good then $A^TA$ is even better."

So what is even better about $A^TA$, what are the benefits of $A^TA$ being invertible, symmetric, and positive definite?

Comment: positive definiteness is good for numerical computations!

Comment: What do you know about linear algebra so far?  Do you know about eigenvalues?  Orthogonal matrices?  The spectral theorem?  Rayleigh's theorem?  The min max (Courant-Fischer) theorem?

Comment: Well, if dealing with real matrix, then being symmetric renders $\;A^tA\;$ orthogonally diagonalizable, which is very nice. Also, if we're dealing with an inner product space, eigenvectors of this matrix corresponding to different eigenvalues are not only linearly independent but even pairwise orthogonal, and **also** all its eigenvalues are non-negative, which then means this matrix has a square root matrix. These indeed are good things in several levels.

Comment: I'm looking for why it is good 'in practise'. E.g. in what way is it good for numerical computations?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I haven't covered the spectral theorem or the ones following it.

Comment: As a consequence of the spectral theorem, the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of symmetric matrices are "nice".  A positive definite matrix has all those properties *and* all of its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: In what way are the eigvalues and eigvectors nice? And then you say for a positive definite matrix we have that niceness but they eigvalues are also positive. What does this enable us to do? I'm looking for an example from some field such as numerical analysis?

Comment: @sonicboom missed your comment earlier.  What do you know about numerical analysis?  Anything about optimization?  Convex functions?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Numerical anlayis: I'm currently going through FDM, FEM and FVM from material I've downloaded and MIT videos. Optimization, another module I never got to take :'-(  , I've downloaded alot of material for this too but haven't gone through it yet apart from some linear programming stuff..I know a bit about convex functions from coding a gradient descent neural network.

Comment: @sonicboom so the gist is that we can find eigenvalues of positive semidefinite matrices by minimizing (or maximizing) a convex function over the appropriate domain.  This means that we can find eigenvalues using all the nice methods like gradient descent or, more commonly, Krylov subspace conjugate gradient.

Comment: Also, linearly independent eigenvectors can always be taken to be orthonormal.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).